# Span font is not displayed correctly

Tags: html, css, styles, font-face

in my website span tags shown badly text (like bottom image).
[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAe7R.png)

but label font shown smoothly.

I tried to add below css attributes to make better, but I did not get result:

```
.yekan-font {
    font-family: 'Yekan', Tahoma;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}
```

how to smooth font in html tags?

please help me.

Comment: I solved by `font-weigth : 700`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ! your stylesheet not works. 
I tested in chrome browser.